# Copy only specific folder structure from a given tree with specific file type

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PS script for backing up the config files in backup folder. Requirement is to copy only folders that have config files.
I am using the `copy-item` command but when I ran the script, I found unnecessary folders were getting copied over.

I have attached screenshot for more details.

Current:

```
Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath –Filter $fileType -Destination $DestinationPath –Recurse
```

I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -File -Include "*.config" -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -like "*$dirname*" }
Copy-Item -Path $files -Destination $dest
```

Only folders with config files should get copied to backup folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, changing your current script to this:

```
$sourcePath      = 'D:\Test'
$destinationPath = 'D:\Result'
$excludeFolder   = 'NoConfigFileFolder'

# create the destination folder if this does not yet exist
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath –Filter '*.config' -Destination $destinationPath –Recurse -Exclude "*$excludeFolder*"
```

should work.

If the structure is like this:

> ```
> D:\TEST
> |   bla1.config
> |   web1.config
> |
> +---ConfigFileFolder
> |       bla.config
> |       web.config
> |
> \---NoConfigFileFolder
>         leavethis.config
> ```

the resulting backup folder looks like this:

> ```
> D:\RESULT
> |   bla1.config
> |   web1.config
> |
> \---ConfigFileFolder
>         bla.config
>         web.config
> ```

Comment: Thanks Theo for your quick response! (I modified your folder structure) According my requirement if the config file doesn't exists in the folder then it should not copy the folder structure. Backup folder should only have config files and folders with config files.

Comment: @HP Please don't edit my answer. If you want to add clarification, do soby editing the question. Anyway, I saw what you tried to change, but that makes no difference at al, because the code -as it is now- will skip the folder `NoConfigFileFolder` no matter what is in there, because that is done with this part `-Exclude "*$excludeFolder*"`